# how to resolve JPA : abstract schema is unknown

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

This is my entity class

```
@Entity

public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int userId;
private String email;
```

As I am querying to the database I get following exceptions:

`The abstract schema type 'User' is unknown.
The state field path 'u.email' cannot be resolved to a valid type.] with root cause`

and this is my query

`TypedQuery<User> query =  em.createQuery("select u from User u where u.email=:email", User.class);
query.setParameter("email", email);
return query.getResultList();`

Do I have register my User class in persistance.xml explicitly?

Am I going wrong somewhere?

EDIT::: I am using eclipse link and following is my persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="Myname" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="smval"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="smval"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-and-extend-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>  
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```